# How to filter "active" HeartRate from HealthKit iOS using predicate?

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, healthkit, heartrate

I am trying to fetch Heart Rate Data from HealthKit iOS by putting filter using **HKQuery.predicateForObjects** By using the following code:

```
let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(withMetadataKey: HKMetadataKeyHeartRateMotionContext, allowedValues: ["active"])


        var interval = DateComponents()
        interval.day = 1
        let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: type, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: [.discreteAverage], anchorDate: startDate, intervalComponents:interval)
        query.initialResultsHandler = { query, results, error in
            if error != nil {

                return
            }
```

I tried different combinations for putting values in a different way

> let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(withMetadataKey:
>   HKMetadataKeyHeartRateMotionContext, allowedValues: ["1"])

OR

> let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(withMetadataKey:
>   HKMetadataKeyHeartRateMotionContext, allowedValues: ["active"])

OR

> let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(withMetadataKey:
>   HKMetadataKeyHeartRateMotionContext, allowedValues:
>   [HKHeartRateMotionContext.sedantary])

I am not getting if am doing anything wrong somewhere in my code.

Please correct me.

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: What about `HKQuery.predicateForObjects(withMetadataKey: HKMetadataKeyHeartRateMotionContext, allowedValues: [HKHeartRateMotionContext.active])`?

Comment: Following error I am getting when I tried with [HKHeartRateMotionContext.active]

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Expected all metadata values to be of type NSNumber, NSDate, or NSString. Received __C.HKHeartRateMotionContext'

Comment: Maybe with `HKHeartRateMotionContext.active.rawValue` instead?

Comment: @PiyushBansal Ok, then what about `HKQuery.predicateForObjects(withMetadataKey: HKMetadataKeyHeartRateMotionContext, allowedValues: ["2"])`?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkheartratemotioncontext/active value is 2. But using rawValue should be better than using number magic.

Comment: @Larme Yup, true that

Comment: But error is not nil? Could you check if you don't put the `allowedValue:` param if it returns at least some values? If it does, check the date of each items, or the interval.